# How do I randomly select multiple images from folders and layer them as a single image in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a personal creative project and need help finding or creating a script that will randomly select 4 images from 4 different folders, stack them and create a series of png composite images as an output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question right, you want to layer images onto each other. For that part I'd recommend using Python's Imaging Library: PIL. It has a function to create composite images. [Here's a short guide on how to use it.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-composite-method/)

In the random images part can be figured out pretty quickly with a Google search. There may be a better way you can find, but the first thing that comes to mind is generating random numbers, where each number is indexed to a directory. Then within each directory you can take a random image by a newly indexed random number. You can use the os library to navigate paths, and it might even have some tools for random images/directories.

Comment: In addition to what Arhan has said, you can get a list of all the images in a directory (and everything else) using the Python `os` library, or preferably, the newer `pathlib` library.
Checkout docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you mean:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# create list of images
images = [
    '/path/to/image/1',
    '/path/to/image/2',
    '/path/to/image/3',
    '/path/to/image/4',
]

# create axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# loop over all images
for image in images:

    # read image to a new variable
    img = mpimg.imread(image)

    # add the new image to the axis
    ax.imshow(img)

# get rid of axis
ax.axis('off')

# ensure there is no excess whitespace
fig.tight_layout()

# save
fig.savefig('new_image.png')
```